Visio -- connect perfectly horizontal connector anywhere on shape
Trying to connect to the side of the shape, where the auto-connection point is defined by the connector.  Adding connection points isn't usually the solution as the connection coming in is based on where the next shape is.  I have selected Glue to... Shape Geometry:

Here there is no auto-connection point on the side of the shape, but the line connects to the shape as shown by the green box, which is the desired behavior.

But when I click shift to drag to keep the line straight, then the thing doesn't actually connect.  There is no green box at the end of the dashed line, which is where the mouse cursor has dragged the end of the line to.

I can tweak it a bit and get close, but I almost always get a small jog if it's connected.  Maybe the jog goes away if I happen to be on a grid line.  Sometimes I can get it to work by taking the end of the straight/unconnected line which is on the side of the shape, and moving the mouse one pixel to the left or right.  That sometimes allows it to connect without the jog, but it feels like a hack compared to a proper solution.

This is not about selecting straight vs. right-angle line.  The 'straight' line just comes out at an angle.
Very frustrating.  There must be a solution.  Thanks.
